# How to get an instance from the DI system?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to recreate `HttpContext.Current` in vNext but I am having trouble with this.

The code so far:

```
public class CurrentContext 
    {
        public IHttpContextAccessor ctx { get; private set; }

        public CurrentContext(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            ctx = accessor;
        }
    }

services.AddTransient<CurrentContext>();
```

I want to use:

```
public static class UserFactory
{
    public static void SetCurrentUser(User u)
    {
        //tryed to get the context but GetService returns null
        IHttpContextAccessor _context = ((CurrentContext)CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider.GetService(serviceType: typeof(CurrentContext))).ctx;
        //add the user to the Session
    }
}
```

How can I now get an instance of `CurrentContext` anywhere in the project?

Answer (score 0):

I do not use the vNext DI system, but I believe you should define an interface for your CurrentContext, e.g.

```
public interface IContextProvider {
     IHttpContextAccessor GetContext();
}
```

And then use

```
public class CurrentContextProvider : IContextProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public CurrentContextProvider(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _context = accessor;
    }

    public IHttpContextAccessor GetContext() {
        return _context;
    }
}
```

And wire

```
services.AddScoped<IContextProvider, CurrentContextProvider>();
```

But if you are going to just use the context, why dont just depend directly on the `IHttpContextAccessor` - where you need it?

Comment: You say to use it where I need it but how do I instantiate `IHttpContextAccessor `? And I was asking how do I get an instance of the registered service?

Comment: Where do you need the instance? You should depend on either the `IHttpContextAccessor` (or `IContextProvider` in my example) in the constructor of the class you need it. Controller, custom class and whatnot.

Comment: I need it in a static context to add/retrive data to/from the user session like the username or user id (from the database)

Comment: Please update your question with that code example - so I can see what you are trying to do. :-)

Comment: vNext DI only supports constructor injection. Service Locator pattern is a bad practice to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the variable of the `CurrentContext` type in constructors of dependent classes:

```
public class SomeClassThatUsesCurrentContext
{
    private readonly SomeClassThatUsesCurrentContext currentContext;

    public SomeClassThatUsesCurrentContext(CurrentContext currentContext)
    {
        if (currentContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("currentContext");

        this.currentContext = currentContext;
    }
}
```

These classes may occur in constructors of other classes. Finally you usually resolve from the DI container the single instance of the high level class. The place where you do it is called [composite root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

And, as @janhartmann says, usually you should use interfaces or abstract classes instead of concrete classes.

Comment: I still have the same problem in a different place: how do I now create an instance of `SomeClassThatUsesCurrentContext`?

Comment: Usually in ASP.NET MVC application you should implement your controller factory. Details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx

Comment: I need the context outside of the controller. I already have it in the controller.

Comment: First, make `UserFactory` instantiable (non-static) class. Get all required classes as parameters in your constructors. To make a single instance of a class use lifetime (lifestyle, scope) capabilities of DI library. Don't use **service locator** cause it's anti-pattern. If you need resolve some classes in some place that is not **composite root**, redesign your solution.